# Orocrm - Missing web api activation UI in backoffice

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

## 1. Web Api

I can't make the api work at all. First of all i was interrested in OROCRM only and not oroCommerce, so my first step was taken here : https://github.com/oroinc/crm-application/tree/master

Great, now i follow the installation link on that github and end up here : https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/setup/dev-environment/manual-installation/crm-ce/

Ok it looks nice and documented, BUT when i reached this part : https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/setup/dev-environment/manual-installation/crm-ce/#step-3-oro-app-name-application-installation

The composer link is wrong :

```
composer create-project oro/commerce-crm-application oroapp --repository=https://satis.oroinc.com
```

It made me loose hours to end up with a OroCommerce installation (correct me if i am wrong, it should be **oro/crm-application**, maybe adapt the documentation ? add a warning or something ?)

Anyways, since i didn't want to start all over again, i kept that oro commerce installation (v. 4.0). But now, its simply impossible to enable the web api.

As the documentation states here, i should be able to activate it in the back office : https://doc.oroinc.com/api/enabling-api-feature/

But, here's what i have in my back office :
[image]

I cleared the cache in prod & dev, i ran the `php bin/console oro:api:doc:cache:clear --env=prod` command in prod & dev as well, Nothing works.

Processes are running, cron task as well, i did not install sample data (fixtures).
Here's the composer.json of the installation :

```
{
  "name": "oro/commerce-crm-application",
  "description": "OroCommerce - an open-source Business to Business Commerce application.\\This package contains a sample application.",
  "license": "OSL-3.0",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Oro, Inc",
      "homepage": "https://www.orocommerce.com"
    }
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {"": "src/"},
    "files": ["src/AppKernel.php"],
    "exclude-from-classmap": ["**/Tests/"]
  },
  "repositories": {
    "composer": {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://packagist.orocrm.com"
    },
    "asset-packagist": {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://asset-packagist.orocrm.com"
    }
  },
  "require": {
    "oro/crm": "4.0.*",
    "oro/platform-serialised-fields": "4.0.*",
    "oro/oauth2-server": "4.0.*",
    "oro/crm-hangouts-call-bundle": "4.0.*",
    "oro/crm-magento-embedded-contact-us": "4.0.*",
    "oro/crm-dotmailer": "4.0.*",
    "oro/crm-zendesk": "4.0.*",
    "oro/commerce": "4.0.*",
    "oro/commerce-crm": "4.0.*"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "behat/behat": "3.4.*",
    "behat/mink": "1.7.x-dev#6d637f7",
    "behat/mink-extension": "2.3.*",
    "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "1.*",
    "behat/symfony2-extension": "2.1.*",
    "nelmio/alice": "3.5.*",
    "theofidry/alice-data-fixtures": "1.0.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "7.5.*",
    "johnkary/phpunit-speedtrap": "3.0.*",
    "mybuilder/phpunit-accelerator": "dev-master",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.3.*",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "2.6.*",
    "sebastian/phpcpd": "4.0.*",
    "phpunit/phpcov": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "4.3.*",
    "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "2.12.6",
    "oro/twig-inspector": "1.0.*"
  },
  "config": {
    "component-dir": "public/bundles/components",
    "bin-dir": "bin",
    "fxp-asset": {
      "enabled": false
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "@build-parameters",
      "@set-permissions",
      "@install-assets",
      "@set-assets-version"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "@build-parameters",
      "@set-permissions",
      "@install-assets",
      "@set-assets-version"
    ],
    "build-parameters": [
      "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters"
    ],
    "set-permissions": [
      "Oro\\Bundle\\InstallerBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::setPermissions"
    ],
    "install-assets": [
      "Oro\\Bundle\\InstallerBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets"
    ],
    "set-assets-version": [
      "Oro\\Bundle\\InstallerBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::setAssetsVersion"
    ]
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true,
  "extra": {
    "symfony-web-dir": "public",
    "symfony-var-dir": "var",
    "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
    "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
      "file": "config/parameters.yml"
    }
  }
}
```

## 2. OAuth Pb

Another issue, i added the public and private keys in the /var folder as stated here :
https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/getting-started/user-menu/oauth/

But i still have the same error message (even after a cache:clear) :
*OAuth authorization is not available as encryption keys configuration was not complete. Please contact your administrator.*

Please i need help !

## EDIT 1

Regarding the Oauth issue, my problem was the **name** of the two files. It is not specified anywhere in the documentation, i actually found the answer looking at bitnami's code, the two files should be named :

- oauth_private.key
- oauth_public.key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Oro commerce installation (v. 4.0).

You are using a 4.0 version, but browse documentation for 4.1 version. In 4.0 there was no such an option and API was always enabled. There is no documentation for the 4.0 version as it's unsupported preview version. Consider to upgrade, or if it's a new installation, better to reinstall the plain CRM

> The composer link is wrong

Yes, you are right, we'll fix it, thanks for noticing.
For now, you can install 4.1 version of OroCRM by following the documentation on a website, except the composer application name, please replace it to the `crm-application`.

> OAuth Pb

Please install 4.1 version of a CRM application and start over. If it will still not work, look for error messages in a `var/logs` folder.

Comment: Works way better in 4.1, API seems accessible @ /api/doc. Regarding OAuth, i have public & private keys in the /var directory but still got the error message. What name should they have (using: id_rsa and id_rsa.pub atm) ?

Comment: make sure the webserver user used in an application has permission to read these files

Comment: Nothing in the var/logs, rights should be ok, gave both files 777 for testing purposes, didnt change anything.

Comment: How do you edit the authentication token expiration ? In your doc it says in config.yml, but whats the name of the parameter if i want to add it ? seriously using orocrm is way too much time consuming...

Comment: see https://github.com/oroinc/oauth2-server/blob/master/README.md#configuration